# KeyCloak returns Forbidden(403) response when access token expires

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak

I am new to KeyCloak, but managed to set up the local KeyCloak server.
As a client I am using postman to test the authentication part.
I am able to get the access token when I enter the OAuth2.0 credentials in postman and able to make a request to access the API.

As the default expire time for the access token is 5 min, when I try again after 5 min to access the API I get Forbidden 403 response from KeyCloak.
I expect this should be Unauthorised(401)

If I provide a user credential that doesn't have permission to access the resource then also I get Forbidden 403 response.

How to tell I am getting 403 because of user authorization issue or because of expired access token?

Thanks,
Vikas

Comment: I tried what you described and I get 401 after token expiration. If I use token of user that does not have admin role I get 403.

Comment: Yes, the user which i'm using is a non-admin

Comment: Yes, but when my admin access token expires I get 401. You don't?

Comment: @andrija I am also facing the same issue Vikas mentioned. Getting 403 for both access limitation and token expiration

Comment: any updates on the following issue?